# Androidでアプリ内のMP3を再生する際のPermission設定

Tags: android, monaca, cordova, mp3

Android用アプリでMP3ファイルを効果音として再生するためにcordovaのMediaプラグインを有効にしたところ、ビルドした際に以下のパーミッションが自動的に設定されてしまいます。（プロジェクト内のAndroidManifest.xmlには追加していません）

- 端末ステータスと端末IDの読み込み
- 録音
- ユーザーメモリ（本体）内のコンテンツを変更／削除
- 保護されたストレージへのテストアクセス
- オーディオ設定を変更

MP3を再生したいだけなので上記のパーミッションは不要なのですが、全て無効（設定なし）にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

なお、cordovaのバージョンは4.1.0を利用しています。

Answer (score 1):

残念ながら `cordova-plugin-media` を使用する場合には、当該プラグインが多機能をサポートしている関係で全て無効にする、ということは難しいかと思います。

直接の回答にはなりませんが、別のプラグインを使用してみると良いかもしれません。プラグインは [Cordovaのプラグインページ](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)から探すこともできます。

また、使用しようとしているプラグインがどのようなパーミッションを求めているかを事前に知りたい場合に調べる方法としては、公開されているソースコードの `plugin.xml` 内で `uses-permission` を調べてみるとわかるかと思います。

参考までに、 `cordova-plugin-media` のリンクを載せておきますが、質問に記載されている通り、このプラグインでは、録音、オーディオの設定変更、書き込み、端末の状態の読み込みの権限を要求しているようですね。

参考情報：[cordova-plugin-media/plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/plugin.xml)